# funny things with scope.lastLessOne

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This AngularJS code works perfect:

```
scope.last = {name:null, list:[]};
        scope.llOne = {name:null, list:[]};
        scope.first = {name:null, list: []};
        scope.listNodes = [];

        //Eventos vista
        scope.expandNode = function (node){

            if ((!scope.last.name) && (!scope.llOne.name) && (!scope.first.name)){
                scope.llOne.name = node.column0;
                scope.llOne.list = scope.listNodes;
            } else if ((!scope.last.name) && (!scope.first.name)){
                scope.last.name = node.column0;
                scope.last.list = scope.listNodes;
            } else if (!scope.first.name) {
                scope.first.name = scope.llOne.name;
                scope.first.list = scope.llOne.list;
                scope.llOne.name = scope.last.name;
                scope.llOne.list = scope.last.list;
                scope.last.name = node.column0; 
                scope.last.list = scope.listNodes;
            } else {
                scope.llOne.name = scope.last.name;
                scope.llOne.list = scope.last.list;
                scope.last.name = node.column0; 
                scope.last.list = scope.listNodes;
            }

            busquedaDireccionService.expandNode(node).then(function (data){
                scope.listNodes = data;
            }, function (error) {
                var properties = $injector.get(profile);
                $state.go(properties.errorState,{msg:'ERROR_SRV_CALLEJERO'});
                throw error;
            });
        };
```

But this other does not:

```
scope.last = {name:null, list:[]};
        scope.lastLessOne = {name:null, list:[]};
        scope.first = {name:null, list: []};
        scope.listNodes = [];

        //Eventos vista
        scope.expandNode = function (node){

            if ((!scope.last.name) && (!scope.lastLessOne.name) && (!scope.first.name)){
                scope.lastLessOne.name = node.column0;
                scope.lastLessOne.list = scope.listNodes;
            } else if ((!scope.last.name) && (!scope.first.name)){
                scope.last.name = node.column0;
                scope.last.list = scope.listNodes;
            } else if (!scope.first.name) {
                scope.first.name = scope.lastLessOne.name;
                scope.first.list = scope.lastLessOne.list;
                scope.llOne.name = scope.last.name;
                scope.llOne.list = scope.last.list;
                scope.last.name = node.column0; 
                scope.last.list = scope.listNodes;
            } else {
                scope.lastLessOne.name = scope.last.name;
                scope.lastLessOne.list = scope.last.list;
                scope.last.name = node.column0; 
                scope.last.list = scope.listNodes;
            }

            busquedaDireccionService.expandNode(node).then(function (data){
                scope.listNodes = data;
            }, function (error) {
                var properties = $injector.get(profile);
                $state.go(properties.errorState,{msg:'ERROR_SRV_CALLEJERO'});
                throw error;
            });
        };
```

It is funny but, if I use a variable with the name "lastLessOne" in the scope of a controller, in the view, the variable always has the value of undefined. If change de name of the variable everything seems be fine.

Does anyone why?

Comment: can you reproduce same error in plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

Both code working fine. There should be some other mistakes in your code.

See Demo for `lastLessOne` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20744/)

See Demo for `llOne` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20747/)

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    {{lastLessOne}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it depends on view that used OP